# I am looking for an example to collect GA data from Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, google-analytics

I have tried to find a way to get Google Analytic data into my Excelsheet using VBA, I can find a lot of information, but it seems to be either depricated April 30 2015 or comercial, and I only want it for my private project...
The best point I have found is this:
http://analytics.blogspot.se/2009/08/analytics-data-in-excel-through-our-api.html

Right now I collect data from GA as a csv file, add my VBA script and run my function, but it would be a lot nicer to be able to collect it directly from my workbook...

Comment: I forgot to add that I use Excel 2007

Answer (score 1):

Frankly I think [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) is your best chance for automated collection of data from GA. It could work as follows:

1. Create a simple Python script where Selenium downloads the csv file from GA
2. From your workbook run the script using Shell ("python your_script.py")
3. Next upload the csv file to your workbook e.g. via ADODB.Connection

Comment: Thanks - sounds like a good way to do it, I did not consider involving another program, was hoping that I could be done directly, but worth giving a shot and will add Phyton to my "know about" list :-)

Comment: I would say investing in learning Python will certainly be worthwhile. You can also try the Internet Explorer object in VBA - although this will be a world of pain :)

Comment: Thanks - and learning Python was on my list when my daughter wanted to learn about it, but then she switched and it lost my attention, but I clearly see a purpose here - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets has a really user-friendly and feature rich integration with GA via [the Google Analytics Spreadsheet add-on](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on). You can run regular, automated reports this way and export as CSV if you like.

Comment: Thanks, I will study Google spreadsheets - the VBA/Excel was to also learn VBA in Excel, but this looks like a good option and is truly worth to investigate!